# Cannot implement a JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript

I've found this code

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('#header').css({
        //Why this 15, because in the CSS, we have set left 15, so as we scroll, we would want this to  remain at 15px left
        'left': $(this).scrollLeft() + 15  
    });
});
```

And it does exactly what I need, but I have no idea how to implement it in my HTML or CSS. Can anyone help me out? I'd truly appreciate it.

Comment: If it does what you need, where are you stuck?

Comment: Take a look at _any_ page that includes Javascript to see how it's done?

Comment: This code requires jQuery, so you will need to include jQuery as well.

Comment: How do you know it does exactly what you need if you don't know how to run it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code uses jQuery, so you need to have included jQuery in the page.

Because it's JavaScript, you need to use a `<script />` tag. You can add the code inline (which I'll do, as it's easier to explain), but you should look into adding it in a separate JS file and including it.

Add this in your HTML anywhere;

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> <!-- Include jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $('#header').css({
            //Why this 15, because in the CSS, we have set left 15, so as we scroll, we would want this to  remain at 15px left
            'left': $(this).scrollLeft() + 15  
        });
    });
</script>
```

Normally you'd have to add a ready handler, but you don't if you're attaching to window, as it always exists.

Comment: Thank you so much, Perfect! I really appreciate your help. I didn't know how to activate jQuery... Everyone starts somewhere :)